# How do I use Random generators in elm 0.17 with a user-specified seed?

Tags: random, elm

In Elm 0.17, I'd like to run a program that relies on random numbers, but I'd like to have a user-specified seed. This is to have reproducible results across multiple user sessions: users who enter the same seed should see the same results.

But I can't figure out how to affect the behavior of built-in functions like:

```
Random.list 10 (Random.int 0 100)
```

With a call like the one above, I want to get the same list of 10 random numbers each time I feed in the same seed. But I can't figure out how to feed in a seed at all. I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Overview

Generating a random value with [Random](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Random), using user-specified seed is possible with [Random.step](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.5/Random#step)

You need to specify a [Generator](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.5/Random#Generator) and a [Seed](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.5/Random#Seed), where `Generator a` is a function to produce random values of `a` type, using integer `Seed`

To create a `Seed` from integer, you need to use [Random.initialSeed](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.5/Random#initialSeed) function, since `Seed` is not a plain integer, it's a data-structure containing meta-information for the the next steps of the `Generator`

#### Random.step

`Generator a -> Seed -> (a, Seed)`

Calling [Random.step](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.5/Random#step) will return a new state `(a, Seed)`, where `a` is your random value, and `Seed` is the seed, required for generating the next random value.

## Example

I have made a comprehensive example, which shows how to use generator for producing random values: [**Random value with user-specified seed**](https://github.com/halfzebra/elm-examples/blob/master/examples/random-user-seed/Main.elm)

The example might be too big for the answer so I will highlight the most important parts:

#### Create a generator

```elm
generator : Int -> Generator (List Int)
generator length =
    Random.list length (Random.int 0 100)
```

#### Step through generator

The `seed` might be specified through user input, or you can pass it as flags upon start-up.

```elm
Random.step (generator 10) seed
```

Comment: This is incredibly helpful. Could you also explain how I'd connect this back to my "app" through a Cmd, so the result can flow into my "update" function?

Comment: @Bosh you don't need `Cmd` in this case. I have updated the [example](https://github.com/halfzebra/elm-examples/blob/master/examples/random-user-seed/Main.elm#L42) to make the logic more explicit. The result is always there!

Comment: Most illuminating, thanks again! One thing I'm confused about is the recommendations from the examples and guide, which seem to convey the idea that a Cms is the appropriate way to achieve this kind of behavior. Am I going against the grain of what Elm recommends or supports?

Comment: @Bosh `Cmd` is used, when you don't  have user-specified `Seed`, in this case it relies on current time-stamp, and it is handled as I/O, if you want more details about that, I would recommend to ask another question.

Comment: Trivial thing: superfluous `)` in the last line of code. Also, with Elm 0.19, it seems that `seed` has to be more than just an integer - `seed = Random.initialSeed <int-value>` seems to work.

Answer (score 4):

The expression that you specified returns a `Generator`.  The function that generates random values is `step` which takes as arguments a `Generator` and a `Seed`.  A Seed can be created with the function `initialSeed` which takes an `Int` that can be specified by the user as argument.

The same argument to `initialSeed` will result in the same `Seed` as output which will result in the same `List` of random `Int` values each time.  The function below illustrates this.

```
randomSequence : Int -> List Int
randomSequence int = 
    let gen = Random.list 10 (Random.int 0 100)
        s = initialSeed int
        (res, ns) = step gen s  
    in res
```

Comment: I really appreciate your response!  Could you also explain how I'd connect this back to my "app" through a Cmd, so the  result can flow into my "update" function?

Comment: Here's what I used to test:  https://github.com/dc25/how-do-i-use-random-generators-in-elm-0-17-with-a-user-specified-seed/blob/master/Main.elm .  In this example the seed is the entire model so that's what gets updated by the updated function.  The view function then evaluates the list of random numbers.  Another way to do this would have been to have the update function compute the list of randoms and store that in the model.